# non unit elements form an additive group of Zn iff n is power of prime

Tags: ring-theory

My approach as follows:
Let non-units' subgroup be A = {x / (x,n) = d > 1 for if d = 1 means unit}

let x, y $\in$ A then (x,n) = d1 > 1 and (y, n) = d2 > 1
(x-y, n) = d1 - d2 ==> (d1 - d2) > 1 ...
After that i am struck.

Another nasty way i got --> characteristic of ring whose non-units form a group is power of prime. We knw that if char R = power of prime, then order of G = power of that prime.

Comment: Why should $(x-y,n)=(d_1-d_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a,b$ are distinct primes dividing $n$.  They are coprime, so $ar+bs=1$ for some integers $r,s$.

But neither $ar$ nor $bs$ are units mod $n$, because they aren't coprime with $n$. They also add up to a unit.

So if nonunits are closed under addition, only one prime can divide $n$.

---

Conversely, consider $\mathbb Z/{p^k}$. An element is a unit here iff it is coprime with $p$, so a nonunit $x$ will satisfy $p|x$.  But obviously the sum of two things divisible by $p$ is divisible by $p$.